# Joining XML and Oracle SQL throws ORA Exception

Tags: xml, oracle, join

I try to merge xml code and Oracle SQL code in 1 table. 
My XML structure looks like

```
<Statuses>
  <Status id="FS_MAIN" status="Main folder" isException="0"/> 
  <Status id="FS_PROCESSING" status="Processing subfolder" isException="0"/> 
</Statuses>
```

My sql looks like

```
select db.status, count(db.id) as "Number of items", max(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20000101','yyyymmdd')+(SYSDATE - db.time_event),'hh24:mi:ss')) as "Time in system"
from MyDb db
where db.seq_number = (select max(dm2.SEQ_NUMBER) from MyDb dm2 where dm2.id= db.id) and db.technology = 'Repository'
group by db.status
```

I use Logi analytics to merge this, I use following structure

[image: Logi structure]

To explain this, Logi is a graphical tool to compile graphical charts into html pages.

My Query is the SQL query, I tested and compiled this in Oracle SQL developper, it works.

The statuslayer is the XML-file, I guess here is the problem.

To make a join I want to make a statusMatch on the status values, but this doesn't work when I compile.

I get the following exception:

> **Logi Debugger Trace Report**
>
> There was an error while processing your request.
>
> The error was:
>
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your table MyDb is not there or you don't have permission to read from it. ( grant select to your user on the table )

The good thing is you get an ORA error, so you are on the database allready.

Comment: Indeed, I lost my permissions, nice! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not connected to the same schema in logi compared to oracle developer? Can you run this query:

SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables;

From your logi application and display the results somehow?

That might give you a clue as to what is going on.